# Hashmap method not accepting defined parameters

Tags: java, hashmap

My assignment is to implement a contact list in a HashMap. All has gone well except for the problem in the code below. the HashMap method put(K key, V value) isnt accepting the defined parameters String, List.

```
public class ContactList(){                   // this is the class
  private HashMap<String, List<String>> map;  // private HashMap field

  public void update(String name, List<String> number){   //method I'm having trouble with
    this.map.remove(name);                    
    this.map.put(name, number)                // HashMap method, main problem.
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
 The method put(String, List<String>) is undefined for the type ContactList
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: doesn't look like there's a problem here. As Paul suggested, plz post more code!

Comment: Are you sure, you are not defining `map` as `ContactList`?

Comment: Are you sure the line number in the exception match to that line?  Seems more like you're calling `this.put` somewhere.

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work, but it also looks like an excerpt. Are you sure that the actual source is `this.map.put(...` and not `this.put(...`?

Comment: the error suggests that you're calling something like `this.put(name, number)`, or `put(name, number)`.. you didn't initialize the map, by the way, this code would give you a `NullPointerException` on `put`

Comment: So this was not inside a constructor, I was definitely unclear with my code, my apologies.

Comment: @TedHopp actually, that definitely was the problem. hrm... perhaps I should copy/paste my code next time. I was trying to rewrite it from memory...

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to invoke and define the class variable in Constructor. And you are writting method update in the same constructor which is also wrong.

Try this out.

```
public class ContactList{

   private Map<String,List<String>> map;

   public ContactList(){
      map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
      String contactName = "Shyama Bhattacharya";
      List<String> constactAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
      contactAddress.add("Parker Colony");
      contactAddress.add("Banglaru");
      update(contactName,contactAddress);
   }

   public void update(String contactName,List<String> contactAddress){
      map.put(contactName,contactAddress);
   }

}
```

This should definitely work!!

Comment: It's not a good idea to call overrideable methods from constructors.

Comment: I have not called overridden methods from constructor. Please elaborate your statement.

Comment: The last line of the constructor is `update(contactName,contactAddress);`. Neither the method nor the class is declared `final`, so it is an overrideable method.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is not method `put(String, List<String>)` in `ContactList`. From what I can see, indeed there are none. But you do have a method `public void update(String name, List<String> number)`. So either invoke `update` or rename `update` to `put`